# Can PowerShell’s Invoke-Sqlcmd be used to run a script that does not return any datasets?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I’ve got a script (file) containing several `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements. Create Proc statements must be submitted as individual batches, so they are all delimited within the file by `GO` statements (each "GO" is on it's own line). When run, the first batch (all the text before the first `GO` statement) runs successfully, but PowerShell returns the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and subsequent batches within that one file are not run.

I have added batches that to the script that do return datasets. When at the start of the script they return results and run without error, and then PowerShell crashes on the first Create Proc command. When the “return dataset” batch is added as the last batch in the file, it does not get run.

Is there a work-around to this? I figure I can use .Net objects (`$Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`) to submit these scripts, but it seems it would be better to use the native PowerShell structures.

I am using PowerShell v4, calling SQL Server 2008. The cmdlet I'm using is:

```
Invoke-sqlcmd  -ServerInstance $SQLInstance  -Database $DBName  -InputFile $UpdateScript  -Variable $SQLCmdVariables  -AbortOnError  -IncludeSQLUserErrors  -OutputSQLErrors $true | Out-File -filePath FileSystem::$DatabaseLog -width 200
```

Answer (score 0):

"GO" is not a real statement, it's a utility command and it's only used in management studio or sqlcmd to split commands batch. Use semicolon "**;**" instead.

Applications based on the ODBC or OLE DB APIs receive a syntax error if they try to execute a GO command. The SQL Server utilities never send a GO command to the server.
Do not use a semicolon as a statement terminator after GO

You can see some details here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This seems to be working for me:

```
$batch = @"
create procedure proc1
as 
    select @@version;
go
create procedure proc2
as 
    select @@version;
go
create procedure proc3
as 
    select @@version;
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $batch
```

Comment: But that's how I'm using it--in SQLCMD, to split commands into batches. (Invoke-Sqlcmd is a wrapper for SQLCMD.) My script contains three CREATE PROCEDURE statements, and these statements cannot be delimited from each other within a single (script, batch, file) with semicolons.